# Sed replacing for cryptography

Tags: bash, sed, cryptography

I am currently making a very simple cryptography tool, using the Linux command `sed`.

I have one problem though...

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "String } "
read String
echo $String | sed -e 's/a/alpha/g' | sed -e 's/b/bravo/g' |
sed -e 's/c/charlie/g' | sed -e 's/d/delta/g' | sed -e 's/e/echo/g' |
sed -e 's/f/foxtrot/g' | sed -e 's/g/golf/g' | sed -e 's/h/hotel/g' |
sed -e 's/i/indigo/g' | sed -e 's/j/juliet/g' | sed -e 's/k/kilo/g' |
sed -e 's/l/lemar/g' | sed -e 's/m/mike/g' | sed -e 's/n/november/g' |
sed -e 's/o/oscar/g' | sed -e 's/p/papa/g' | sed -e 's/q/quebec/g' |
sed -e 's/r/romeo/g' | sed -e 's/s/sierra/g' | sed -e 's/t/tango/g' |
sed -e 's/u/uniform/g' | sed -e 's/v/vector/g' | sed -e 's/w/whiskey/g' |
sed -e 's/x/x-ray/g' | sed -e 's/y/yankee/g' | sed -e 's/z/zulu/g' |
sed -e 's/A/Alpha/g' | sed -e 's/B/Bravo/g' | sed -e 's/C/Charlie/g' |
sed -e 's/D/Delta/g' | sed -e 's/E/Echo/g' | sed -e 's/F/Foxtrot/g' |
sed -e 's/G/Golf/g' | sed -e 's/H/Hotel/g' | sed -e 's/I/Indigo/g' |
sed -e 's/J/Juliet/g' | sed -e 's/K/Kilo/g' | sed -e 's/L/Lemar/g' |
sed -e 's/M/Mike/g' | sed -e 's/N/November/g' | sed -e 's/O/Oscar/g' |
sed -e 's/P/Papa/g' | sed -e 's/Q/Quebec/g' | sed -e 's/R/Romeo/g' |
sed -e 's/S/Sierra/g' | sed -e 's/T/Tango/g' | sed -e 's/U/Uniform/g' |
sed -e 's/V/Vector/g' | sed -e 's/W/Whiskey/g' | sed -e 's/X/X-ray/g' |
sed -e 's/Y/Yankee/g' | sed -e 's/Z/Zulu/g'
```

And when I execute it and put input, this is the output:

```
root@kali:~# ./String2Phonetic 
String } StackOverflow
SierratangoalemikearomeopapahosierracaromeotangoelemikearomeoachosierracaromeotangoelemikearomeoaromeolemikearomeoinosierracaromeovectoremberomeodigosierracaromeoechosierracaromeotangoelemikearomeoosierracaromeokilemikearomeoosierracaromeoOscarvectorechosierracaromeotangoelemikearomeoosierracaromeoromeofosierracaromeoxrayankeetangoromeoosierracaromeotangolemikearomeoosierracaromeowhiskeyankee
root@kali:~#
```

When it should be (based on Australia phonetics)

```
root@kali:~# ./String2Phonetic 
String } StackOverflow
SierratangoalphacharliekiloOscarvectorechoromeofoxtrotlemaroscarwhiskey
```

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/.*/\n&\n:alpha:bravo:charlie:delta:echo:foxtrot:golf:hotel:indigo:juliet:kilo:lemur:mike:november:oscar:papa:quebec:romeo:sierra:tango:uniform:vector:whiskey:x-ray:yankee:zulu/;:a;s/\n([^\n])(.*\n.*:\1([^:]*))/\1\3\n\2/I;ta;s/\n.*//' file
```

This solution works by a prefixing a newline (a marker) to the front of the word to be translated and appending another newline and a lookup table to the end of the word. Each character is matched with a starting word in the lookup and the newline is used to mark where the matching has occured. Matching is terminated where two newlines are encountered. Substitution uses the `I` flag to match on caseless characters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this only works with one word, e.g if I wanted to do "I Love StackExchange", it would only print "Indigo", not "Indigo Lemaroscarvectorecho" etc...

Comment: Perhaps you could add a space to the lookup table? e.g. `...: `

Comment: I have done that, but i have also realized that characters like `!@#$` etc don't work, I tried putting them in, but I got `EOF` errors

Comment: @MaliciouZzHD when you add punctuation to the lookup table remember that sometimes those characters also have other meanings as metacharacters. So it is best to quote each of them e.g. `:\&` another way would be to have a catch all substitution following an unsuccessful lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Potong's lookup table is neat. A simpler but also longer solution is to first prefix each character with a delimiter that doesn't appear in the plaintext, e.g. `s/./%&/g`, which will turn your string into `%S%t%a%c%k...`. Then instead of matching `S`, you'll match `%S`:

```sed
s/./%&/g
s/%a/&lpha/gi
s/%b/&ravo/gi
s/%c/&harlie/gi
s/%d/&elta/gi
s/%e/&cho/gi
# ...
s/%y/&ankee/gi
s/%z/&ulu/gi
s/%//g
```

The above also uses case-insensitive matches so you don't need double the lines of code to handle upper-case characters. The last line removes the `%`s. Of course, you can use any character in place of `%`, e.g. `\0` or even `\n`.

You can try it online here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#PZC9ksMgDIT7vEfU3elRUqS9BhMZE8D4BHZ@Xt6RZ6SU3@yudmFv@It/Z8Bwanh2CHmZHIZ40IDAbqtKHmFynCMp3xAod/MSgp/MOiLUZ@falYNwHhUmgU5ZKSLMtxgseUdYpcKCCSFm07IUFsdKRaRkW2a5uVEZyNSK0PzXuyC4xZb@SwUN5BVZooWso8lVYjZvl@D8HbfK1jhWLsqbDPK9WstDPii2RC/lJ8IPO6PXcSqRLX4fD10VEMO@X7vz6bIRj7k@Pg)

P.S. You don't need to call `sed` 26+ separate times. Call it once with a semicolon or newline between commands or, if you prefer, multiple `-e` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Start with transforming the input to uppercase, then s/A/alpha/, etc.
That way the "p's" in "alpha" don't get changed to "papa", etc.